# Fastest way to debug Adobe Air for Android with Native Extensions

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I'm developing an Air for Android app that requires Native Extensions to perform tasks such as reading from the contacts and sending SMS messages.

Currently I am remotely debugging using Flash Professional and a physical Android Device over wifi.

The problem is that each time I debug the app it takes a while to transfer the app to the device over USB then connect to the debugger over a wifi connection from the device (about 2 minutes every time I need to debug). So in my case if I have to debug 30 times I've spent about an hour waiting to debug.

Is there a more streamline approach to speed this up? Maybe using an emulator or another solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried USB Debugging? should be a bit better than wifi debugging.

Comment: In Flash Pro CS6, under Air for Android Settings -> Deployment -> Android Deployment Type I see Device Release, Emulator Release, and Debug. Under Debug it just says Network Interface for Remote Debugging and I can only choose from my network interfaces